# Добавить ссылку на материал K2

Tags: joomla

Как добавить ссылку на материал из К2 в материале?
Если пользоваться вот этим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
то туда попадают только материалы из родной jooml'ы.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут 2 варианта.

1. Это добвлять ссылку через html Текст - просто и со вкусом.
2. Создавать плагин для редактора. В приципе не так уж и сложно за основу можно взять кнопку добавить материал, но лично по моему мнению это трата лишняя трата сил.

Есть еще вариант - это переправить текущею кнопку, но это не есть хорошо хотябы потому, что при обновлении это слетит.